# NDVI from ESA's Sentinel-2 training data

Tags: qgis, ndvi, sentinel-2

I'am trying to generate an NDVI map using ESA's Sentinel-2 training images, which can be found at https://spot-take5.org. I tried using QGIS's raster calculator to create the NDVI image, however quite unsuccessful, as I can't manage to figure out how the bands correspond to the basic `NDVI = (NIR - VIS)/(NIR + VIS)` formula. Any Python script or other freeware tool would suit me as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, you should take note that the simulated Sentinel-2 images come from the SPOT 4 (and maybe SPOT 5) satellite. So you'll have less bands than with the actual Sentinel-2. For [SPOT 4 and 5](http://www.geo-airbusds.com/en/194-resolution-and-spectral-bands), the bands are

> B1 = green, B2=red, B3=NIR, B4=SWIR

Second, NDVI is more often (NIR-RED)/(NIR+RED), and you should make sure that you have reflectances in order to work with comparable NDVI values.

> Float(image@3-image@2)/Float(image@3+image@2)

UPDATE (Now that "true" Sentinel-2 data become available): with Sentinel-2, for 10 m NDVI, red is band 4 and NIR is band 8